# Trace the IPAddress

Tags: c#

I like to know the IP address of the system from which user is connected to MSTSC or remote system. Here is my problem:-

I have web application wich run on intranet and when user need to access that webapplication they need to login to their office PC. Now to access their office PC user need to connect thorugh VPN. Now i want to know his IP address from which he has done the VPN when he access the webapplication. Your help is appriciated

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

That's something technically impossible to achieve solely inside your web application.

Like you mentioned, the HTTP requests come from the machine inside corporate network, not the machine the end user uses outside. If you know networking well, then those requests only contain IP address of the inner machine, not the outer one.

To acquire the outer machine's IP address, you will have to collect information from the inner machine who sends out the requests.

Since the outer machine has a connection to the inner machine, there should be possibility to collect outer machine information on the inner machine (but it still can be hard if VPN is used, as that means there can be network devices in between, who may hide the outer machine's IP address.

Comment: Lex Thanks for your input. Do i have any way atleast i can track if my application is getting accessed from the vpn connected system.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [HttpWebRequest.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property

```
String address = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a VB6 application with fancy animation and an "**ENHANCE**" button.